# Caching is not working for reverse proxy?

Tags: caching, reverse-proxy, apache2.4

I am unable to cache some of the files coming from reverse proxy url.
The logs coming from logger is listed below.

```
 [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.366812 2014] [cache:debug] [pid 2381:tid 140215825839872] cache_storage.c(664): [client 107.20.138.104:45231] AH00698: cache: Key for entity /store/info.js?(null) is http://tweetwood.mystorelive.com/store/info.js?
        [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.366898 2014] [cache_disk:debug] [pid 2381:tid 140215825839872] mod_cache_disk.c(572): [client 107.20.138.104:45231] AH00709: Recalled cached URL info header http://tweetwood.mystorelive.com/store/info.js?
        [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.366921 2014] [cache_disk:debug] [pid 2381:tid 140215825839872] mod_cache_disk.c(884): [client 107.20.138.104:45231] AH00720: Recalled headers for URL http://tweetwood.mystorelive.com/store/info.js?
        [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.366958 2014] [cache:debug] [pid 2381:tid 140215825839872] cache_storage.c(359): [client 107.20.138.104:45231] AH00695: Cached response for /store/info.js isn't fresh. Adding conditional request headers.
        [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.366971 2014] [cache:debug] [pid 2381:tid 140215825839872] mod_cache.c(486): [client 107.20.138.104:45231] AH00757: Adding CACHE_SAVE filter for /store/info.js
        [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.366982 2014] [cache:debug] [pid 2381:tid 140215825839872] mod_cache.c(520): [client 107.20.138.104:45231] AH00759: Adding CACHE_REMOVE_URL filter for /store/info.js
        [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.366993 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 2381:tid 140215825839872] mod_proxy.c(1100): [client 107.20.138.104:45231] AH01143: Running scheme http handler (attempt 0)
        [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.367007 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 2381:tid 140215825839872] proxy_util.c(2020): AH00942: HTTP: has acquired connection for (localhost)
        [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.367017 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 2381:tid 140215825839872] proxy_util.c(2072): [client 107.20.138.104:45231] AH00944: connecting http://localhost:3000/store/info.js to localhost:3000
        [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.367027 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 2381:tid 140215825839872] proxy_util.c(2194): [client 107.20.138.104:45231] AH00947: connected /store/info.js to localhost:3000
        [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.591935 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 2381:tid 140215825839872] proxy_util.c(2035): AH00943: http: has released connection for (localhost)
        [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.592815 2014] [deflate:debug] [pid 2381:tid 140215825839872] mod_deflate.c(764): [client 107.20.138.104:45231] AH01384: Zlib: Compressed 304058 to 38873 : URL /store/info.js
        [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.593047 2014] [cache:debug] [pid 2381:tid 140215825839872] mod_cache.c(1326): [client 107.20.138.104:45231] AH00769: cache: Caching url: /store/info.js
        [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.593067 2014] [cache:debug] [pid 2381:tid 140215825839872] mod_cache.c(1332): [client 107.20.138.104:45231] AH00770: cache: Removing CACHE_REMOVE_URL filter.
        [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.593844 2014] [cache_disk:debug] [pid 2381:tid 140215825839872] mod_cache_disk.c(1349): [client 107.20.138.104:45231] AH00737: commit_entity: Headers and body for URL http://tweetwood.mystorelive.com/store/info.js? cached.
        [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.951416 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 2380:tid 140215809054464] proxy_util.c(2035): AH00943: http: has released connection for (localhost)
        [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.952371 2014] [deflate:debug] [pid 2380:tid 140215809054464] mod_deflate.c(764): [client 118.67.252.150:31420] AH01384: Zlib: Compressed 340236 to 40155 : URL /store/info.js, referer: http://tweetwood.mystorelive.com/
        [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.952585 2014] [cache:debug] [pid 2380:tid 140215809054464] mod_cache.c(1326): [client 118.67.252.150:31420] AH00769: cache: Caching url: /store/info.js, referer: http://tweetwood.mystorelive.com/
        [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.952605 2014] [cache:debug] [pid 2380:tid 140215809054464] mod_cache.c(1332): [client 118.67.252.150:31420] AH00770: cache: Removing CACHE_REMOVE_URL filter., referer: http://tweetwood.mystorelive.com/
        [Wed Jan 15 06:40:49.953449 2014] [cache_disk:debug] [pid 2380:tid 140215809054464] mod_cache_disk.c(1349): [client 118.67.252.150:31420] AH00737: commit_entity: Headers and body for URL http://tweetwood.mystorelive.com/store/info.js? cached., referer: http://tweetwood.mystorelive.com/


 <IfModule mod_cache.c>
      CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
      CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
      CacheStoreNoStore On
       CacheDefaultExpire 600
      CacheMaxExpire 600
        CacheStorePrivate on
       CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie
        CacheIgnoreURLSessionIdentifiers jsessionid
        CacheQuickHandler Off
        CacheIgnoreQueryString On
         CacheDetailHeader on
        CacheHeader on
         KeepAlive off
         CacheKeyBaseURL http://tweetwood.mystorelive.com/
         <IfModule mod_cache_disk.c>
          CacheRoot /var/www/tweetwoodCache
          CacheEnable disk  /
          CacheDisable /admin
           CacheDirLevels 5
            CacheDirLength 3
          LogLevel debug
           CustomLog /var/log/apache2/uncached-requests.log common env=cache-miss
          </IfModule>
          # When acting as a proxy, don't cache the list of security updates
          CacheDisable http://security.update.server/update-list/
          #SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
          </IfModule>
          ProxyRequests off
          <Proxy *>
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all 
           <FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|css|js|html)$">
             Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, proxy-revalidate"
           </FilesMatch>
          </Proxy>
          ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
          ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
      ProxyPreserveHost on
```

Please help me for what I doing wrong here? 
can anybody tell me what's the wrong with above configuration?
Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: i have the same problem have you got it working?

Comment: No I didnt get any solution but switch to nginx which works for me.

Comment: Yes this is what i already did Vijay. Nginx was a killer. Cheers